# Keras GridSearch scikit learn freezes

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, grid-search, hyperparameters

I struggle to implement grid search in Keras using scikit learn. Based on [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/), I wrote the following code:

```python
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

    def create_model():
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(max_len, len(alphabet)), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
            model.add(Dropout(0.85))
            model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(100,))) 
            model.add(Dropout(0.85))
            model.add(Dense(num_output_classes, activation='softmax'))

            adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=1e-6)

            model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=adam,
                      metrics=['accuracy']) 

            return model

    seed = 7
    np.random.seed(seed)

    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, verbose=0)

    batch_size = [10,20]
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
    grid_result = grid.fit(train_data_reduced, train_labels_reduced)

    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

It does not give me any error message, but it just runs on and on forever without printing out anything. I deliberately tried it with very few epochs, very few training examples and very few hyperparameters to search. Without grid search, one epoch runs through extremely fast, so I don’t think that I just need to give it more time. It simply doesn’t do anything.

Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First (always) try with `n_jobs=1` if its working properly and returning in reasonable time or not.

Comment: Updates on this? I have similar the same problem. n_jobs=1 works, but not parallelisation.

Comment: n_jobs=1 returns some results eventually, but it takes way too long, even with very little amount of data on a GPU...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Removing `n_jobs=-1` from your parameters list might help! Also try to not do the hot encoding.